# Placing Prestashop's horizontal menu

Tags: html, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to create a custom Prestashop template but I'm struggling a bit. I'm trying to create a layout very similar to the default layout with the cart in the top right of the page, then a full width horizontal menu underneath it.

My header has 3 columns, the first one with the logo, the second one with a phone number and the third one should hold the cart.

In my third column I've placed the {$HOOK_TOP} to enable me to add the cart there.

```
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header" class="large-12 columns">
       <div class="row">

            <div id="logo" class="large-3 columns">LOGO HERE</div>

            <div id="contactus" class="large-3 columns">PHONE HERE</div>

            <div id="header_right" class="large-3 columns">
                 {$HOOK_TOP}
            </div>

       </div>
</div>
<!-- /Header -->
```

The problem is that the Horizontal menu also uses {$HOOK_TOP}, so my menu is displayed in the top right of my header.

The default theme works in the same way, but when I view the source they've somehow moved the menu module outside of the #header_right div and placed it underneath so that it can be displayed full width across the layout.

Does anyone know how they have done this?

Thank you

Comment: I didn't take a look at how they do it, but I usually creates another hook for the menu. This is easy to do and avoid a lot of hacky css

Comment: Oh, and if you want me to extend on how to create another hook for the menu feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks, i did this and it works perfectly.